# Cisco AnyConnect VPN - how to use port 443?

Tags: cisco, vpn

We have a Cisco Anyconnect VPN SSL configured on Outside interface and port 7443.

I'd like to change this port to 443 (already used with the current public IP) but with a new public IP pool.

What is/are the best way(s) to do that?

It's a CISCO ASA-5506.
Here is my configuration:

```
ASA Version 9.5(2)
!
hostname asa-5506-1
ip local pool Pool_VpnSSL 172.16.253.10-172.16.253.50 mask 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 channel-group 1 mode on
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 channel-group 1 mode on
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
 channel-group 1 mode on
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/5
 channel-group 1 mode on
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/6
 channel-group 1 mode on
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/8
 nameif outside1
 security-level 50
 ip address MY.PUBLIC.IP 255.255.255.224
!
interface Port-channel1
 lacp max-bundle 8
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Port-channel1.100
 vlan 100
 nameif dmz
 security-level 50
 ip address 172.16.200.2 255.255.255.224
!
interface Port-channel1.210
 vlan 210
 nameif employees
 security-level 99
 ip address 172.16.11.254 255.255.252.0
!
interface Port-channel1.219
 vlan 219
 nameif servers
 security-level 50
 ip address 192.168.15.254 255.255.240.0
!
nve 1
 encapsulation vxlan
boot system disk0:/asa952-lfbff-k8.SPA
boot system disk0:/asa942-lfbff-k8.SPA
ftp mode passive
clock timezone CEST 2
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object network network-dmz
 subnet 172.16.200.0 255.255.255.224
object network network-servers
 subnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.240.0
object network network-employees
 subnet 172.16.8.0 255.255.252.0
object service http
 service tcp source eq www
object service https
 service tcp source eq https
object network host-prod-web
 host 172.16.200.1
object network NETWORK_OBJ_172.16.253.0_26
 subnet 172.16.253.0 255.255.255.192
object network Pool-VpnSSL
 range 172.16.253.10 172.16.253.50
object network host-dhcp01
 host 172.16.11.252
 description DHCP
object network gateway-anyconnect
 host my.public.ip.X
object-group protocol TCPUDP
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
access-list outside-in extended permit udp any object network-servers eq 1194
access-list outside-in extended permit tcp any object network-dmz eq www
access-list outside-in extended permit tcp any object network-dmz eq https
access-list outside-in extended permit tcp any object network-servers eq www
access-list outside-in extended permit tcp any object network-servers eq 8080
access-list outside-in extended permit ip object Pool-VpnSSL 192.168.0.0 255.255.240.0
access-list outside-in extended deny ip any any
access-list outside-out extended permit ip object network-employees any
access-list outside-out extended permit ip object network-servers any
access-list outside-out extended permit ip object network-dmz any
access-list outside-out extended deny ip any any
access-list servers-in extended permit ip any any
access-list servers-out extended permit ip object network-employees any
access-list servers-out extended permit tcp any any eq www
access-list servers-out extended permit tcp any any eq https
access-list servers-out extended permit udp any any eq syslog
access-list servers-out extended permit udp any any eq 1194
access-list servers-out extended permit tcp any any eq 8080
access-list servers-out extended deny ip any any
access-list employees-in extended permit ip any any
access-list employees-in extended deny ip any any
access-list employees-out extended permit tcp object network-servers any eq 61043
access-list employees-out extended deny ip any any
access-list dmz-in extended permit tcp object network-dmz any eq smtp
access-list dmz-in extended permit udp object network-dmz any eq domain
access-list dmz-in extended permit tcp object network-dmz any eq www
access-list dmz-in extended permit tcp object network-dmz any eq https
access-list dmz-in extended deny ip any any
access-list dmz-out extended permit tcp any any eq ssh
access-list dmz-out extended permit tcp any any eq www
access-list dmz-out extended permit tcp any any eq https
access-list dmz-out extended deny ip any any
access-list my.lan extended permit ip 192.168.0.0 255.255.240.0 192.168.16.0 255.255.252.0
access-list my.lan extended permit ip 192.168.16.0 255.255.252.0 192.168.0.0 255.255.240.0
access-list my.lan extended permit ip 172.16.8.0 255.255.252.0 192.168.16.0 255.255.252.0
access-list my.lan extended permit ip 192.168.16.0 255.255.252.0 172.16.8.0 255.255.252.0
access-list my.lan extended permit ip 192.168.16.0 255.255.252.0 172.16.12.0 255.255.255.0
access-list my.lan extended permit ip 172.16.12.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.16.0 255.255.252.0
access-list VPNSSL extended permit ip object Pool-VpnSSL 192.168.0.0 255.255.240.0 log disable
access-list Split_network_Server standard permit 192.168.0.0 255.255.240.0
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging trap alerts
logging asdm informational
logging host servers 192.168.10.56
mtu outside1 1500
mtu dmz 1500
mtu employees 1500
mtu servers 1500
no failover
no monitor-interface service-module
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-751-90.bin
asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
nat (dmz,outside1) source static host-prod-web interface service http http
nat (dmz,outside1) source static host-prod-web interface service https https
nat (any,outside1) source dynamic any interface
nat (any,outside1) source static any any destination static NETWORK_OBJ_172.16.253.0_26 NETWORK_OBJ_172.16.253.0_26 no-proxy-arp route-lookup
access-group outside-in in interface outside1
access-group outside-out out interface outside1
access-group dmz-in in interface dmz
access-group dmz-out out interface dmz
access-group employees-in in interface employees
access-group employees-out out interface employees
access-group serversin in interface servers
access-group serversout out interface servers
route outside1 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 MY.PUBLIC.IP.X 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 sctp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
aaa-server MY.LAN protocol radius
aaa-server MY.LAN (servers-) host 192.168.9.14
 key *****
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication enable console my.LAN LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console my.LAN LOCAL
aaa authentication http console my.LAN LOCAL
aaa authentication secure-http-client
http server enable 8443
http 172.16.8.0 255.255.252.0 employees
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server community *****
sysopt noproxyarp outside2
sysopt noproxyarp outside1
sla monitor 1
 type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho 192.168.15.254 interface outside1
 num-packets 3
 frequency 10
sla monitor schedule 1 life forever start-time now
service sw-reset-button
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set eurotunnel-set esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set my.lan-set esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set test esp-null esp-none
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto dynamic-map dynmap 1 match address my.lan
crypto dynamic-map dynmap 1 set ikev1 transform-set my.lan-set
crypto dynamic-map dynmap 1 set security-association lifetime seconds 86400
crypto map my.lan-map 1 ipsec-isakmp dynamic dynmap
crypto map my.lan-map interface outside1
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
 keypair ASDM_TrustPoint0
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_TrustPoint0
 certificate 108aefd63320fad1986731f8
 ...
  quit
crypto isakmp identity address
crypto isakmp nat-traversal 10
crypto isakmp disconnect-notify
crypto ikev2 remote-access trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
crypto ikev1 enable outside1
crypto ikev1 policy 1
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
!
track 1 rtr 1 reachability
telnet timeout 5
no ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 employees
ssh timeout 60
ssh version 2
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 5
!
dhcprelay server 192.168.9.1 servers
dhcprelay setroute employees
dhcprelay timeout 90
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
ntp server 192.168.9.1 prefer
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint0 outside1
webvpn
 port 7443
 enable outside1
 dtls port 7443
 anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-3.1.14018-k9.pkg 1
 anyconnect enable
 tunnel-group-list enable
 cache
  disable
 error-recovery disable
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
group-policy GroupPolicy_VPNSSL internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_VPNSSL attributes
 wins-server none
 dns-server value 192.168.9.1
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ssl-client
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value Split_network_Server
 default-domain value my.lan
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
username netadmin password zz1GrwawHuLEvLaB encrypted privilege 15
tunnel-group VPNSSL type remote-access
tunnel-group VPNSSL general-attributes
 address-pool Pool_VpnSSL
 authentication-server-group my.LAN
 accounting-server-group my.LAN
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_VPNSSL
tunnel-group VPNSSL webvpn-attributes
 group-alias VPNSSL enable
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
  inspect pptp
  inspect icmp
 class class-default
  user-statistics accounting
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
: end
```

Comment: Type of equipment and configurations from them would be a great help for us to understand what you are trying to achieve. If you post configurations please remember to remove public IP's and passwords/users etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to change this port to 443 (already used with the current public IP) but with a new public IP pool.

To my knowledge, you would not be able to do this. Webvpn is enabled on your external outside1 interface thus it is associated with the IP address of this interface.

In this case, you have to change the current Web_Server service (https/443) in DMZ network which is attached to current IP address of outside1 interfface:

- Use (NAT) another (2nd) public IP for Web_Server in DMZ, and you have to change public Web_Server DNS record as well. This approach is better and the change is invisible to end users.
- Or use another TCP port (such as: 8080) rather than 443, so TCP port 443 will be free for Anyconnect.

There were discussions about this matter (Link [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/vpn/anyconnect-webvpn-different-ip/td-p/2035349) and [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/442980-cisco-asa-one-public-ip-vpn-https-traffic-help)).

Comment: Mh yes unfortunately that's what i was thinking about too...

I think i'll go for the 1st solution, it seems to be the best so far.

Thank you for your time and your solutions.